# 404 with CodeIgniter on form submit

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I found this has been asked by many. But none of the answers could resolve my issue. So posting a new thread.

controllers\login.php

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
  } 

  public function index(){
      $this->load->view('login/index');
  } 
  public function process(){
      echo 'hi';
  }
}
```

views\login\index.php

```
<?php echo form_open('login/process'); ?>
<button type="submit" >OK</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

config\config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/aiop/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';
```

root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

when I launch the application using `http://localhost/aiop/` it is launching the `login/index.php`. When I click on button on the page, it is trying to navigate to `http://localhost/aiop/login/process` and says `404`

Answer (score 0):

Ah At last I figured it out. The application folder name was in a different case (AIOP) than what is defined in config (aiop). Though this seems silly answer, I thought it could help someone who came from non-case sensitive world (Windows/.NET)